# Dynamically naming functions in python

Tags: python-3.x, class, eval

I am creating a function that creates an arbitrary class. Currently, it takes in three inputs, an initialization function, a dictionary containing function/methods for the class, and a parent class (which is by default `object`). However, currently adding functions to the class uses the exec function, which I don't want to use.

```
def createClass(init, functions, Parent = object):

    class ResultClass (Parent):
        pass

    ResultClass.__init__ = init
    for name in functions:
        s = 'ResultClass.' + name + ' = functions[name]'
        exec(s)

    return ResultClass
```

How can I rewrite the portion inside the for loop to remove the exec?

Comment: Maybe `setattr`?

Comment: @root I tried setattr and that worked, thanks.